# How to write a scrapy program that scrapes multiple webpages?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So, I have project to scrape job data from different websites

There are list of 2000 website Url (**each have different html structure**) in excel sheet, I have to pass these url in scrapy and scrape following data Title, Company, Country, Category, Description, Apply link, Date crawled, Date updated, Date created.

It will be two steps Process:

1. going to the Website url from excel sheet and scraping all the job link from the page.
2. crawling link scraped from first step and scraping following data Title, Company, Country, Category, Description, Apply link, Date crawled, Date updated, Date created.

**I want to ask if that possible in scrapy and, if yes how should I write the program.**

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm all web pages are in List-Detail mode? This means, there is a [list page] (which contains many jobs, could be visited by page number), and all the job detail fields are on the [job detail page]

If yes, we can define field_name and XPath map. Something like:

1. website1: job_title:xpath1 category:xpath2 ...
2. website2: job_title:xpath21 category:xpath22

There are many situations we need to consider.

1. Are all fields exists in HTML directly? Or some websites use JSON
   format ajax request?
2. Are all fields exists in the same format source (all in HTML or all in JSON)? Some fields may exists in HTML code of page, some fields exists in JSON format script
3. Are all the websites use GET method to request the [list page]? Or some websites use POST? If the website use POST, do they post JSON format payload or key=value pairs form data?

In a word, it's hard to make all things clear here.